# How can I sync Stickies across Mac devices?

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore, stickies

The MacOS Stickies app does not allow syncing between devices. Is there any way I can do it?

Note: This solution https://superuser.com/a/393013 does not answer my question as Notational Velocity does not allow Stickies to stick on the Desktop.

Comment: IMHO, I suggest you move away from Stickies and use a true syncing app like Evernote. This [answer @ Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/392987/how-can-i-synchronize-stickies-between-macs) uses Dropbox to keep your Stickies database in the cloud, but it has some caveats for use that, for me, would make it useless. One of my clients lost tons of Stickies info when her HD crashed hard (and her Time Machine backups were way out of date.) The Stickies data she was able to restore she immediately transferred into Evernote.